# storing the list of object type array into a set of string type

Tags: java

I have fired the below hibernate query which is fetching the data perfectly but the return type is of List as shown below..

```
public List<Object[]> Extractingc()
    {

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(IDetails.class);
        ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
        proList.add(Projections.property("sem"));  //is of string type
        proList.add(Projections.property("tid"));  //is of long type in pojo  *******
                    criteria.setProjection(proList);            
        List<Object[]> settlementIdList =  criteria.list();
        return sst;

    }
```

now the problem comes in java code is that i am putting the result of above method in an an list further in code as shown below...

```
List<Object[]> ioaist =  ioabookandinstrumenthome.Extractingc();
```

now i want that the result of list to be stored in a hashset which is of string type so i created the hashset of string type as shown below...

```
Set<String> ser = new HashSet<String>();
```

now i am storing the result in set as shown below..

```
for (Object[] arr : ioaist) {
ser.add( (String) arr[0] , (String) arr[1] );
}
```

but it will throw the compile time exception , please advise how can I store store the result ultimately in set

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with `ser.add( (String) arr[0] , (String) arr[1] );`

You can't add 2 values to a set. Either you are looking at a Map.add (Key,Value) then change `Set<String> ser = new HashSet<String>();` to `Map<String,String> ser = new HashMap<String,String>(); and`ser.add( (String) arr[0] , (String) arr[1] );`to`ser.put( (String) arr[0] , (String) arr[1] );`

else
change `ser.add( (String) arr[0] , (String) arr[1] );` to `ser.add( (String) arr[0]);  ser.add(String) arr[1] );`